# Mongodb, aggregate nr of items in $group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm doing some aggregation to get some statistics on a how many products there are in cateories.

After some piping I'm down to this:

```
[
  {
     topCategory: "Computer",
     mainCategory: "Stationary"
  },
  {
    topCategory: "Computer",
    mainCategory: "Laptop"
  },
  {
    topCategory: "Computer",
    mainCategory: "Stationary"
  },
  {
    topCategory: "Computer",
    mainCategory: "Stationary"
  },
```

]

Wanted output:

```
[
  {
    name: "Computer",
    count: 4,
    mainCategories: [
      {
         name: "Laptop",
         count: 2
      },
      {
         name: "Stationary",
         count: 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My query so far:

```
let query = mongoose.model('Product').aggregate([
    {
      $match:  {
        project:  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.projectId)
      }
    },
    { $project:  {
        _id: 0,
        topCategory: '$category.top',
        mainCategory: '$category.main',
      }
    },
 ]);
```

I know I need to use `$group` combined with `$sum`. I tried different way's but can't get it work.

Comment: use  group  `{
   $group : { 
    _id : "$topCategory",
    "count" :  { $sum : 1 },
                                mainCategories: { $push:  { name: "$mainCategory"} }
    }
   }
  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case first you should group by `mainCategory` and then group by `topCategory` as below

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "$mainCategory",
    "count": {
      $sum: 1
    },
    "data": {
      "$push": "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": "$data"
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$data.topCategory",
    "count": {
      "$sum": 1
    },
    "mainCategories": {
      "$addToSet": {
    "name": "$_id",
    "count": "$count"
      }
    }
  }
}).pretty()
```